# Why does stddev_over_time increase the bigger the range vector is

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, grafana, standard-deviation, anomaly-detection

I am setting up an anomaly detection for our web application based on rate of traffic at the moment. Traffic is usally approx. 0.6 per second as you can see with this rate query. We have a cluster of several instances of the inspected application, thus i need to aggregate using sum for determining the sum of req/s or avg std deviation below.

```
sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1m]))
```

[image: average rate of traffic per second in 1m interval]

When I do the `stddev_over_time` with an interval of 1m it looks comprehensive. Note that I need to filter out 0's, because sometimes `stddev_over_time` cannot calculate a std deviation when a particular JVM didn't receive traffic on that instant point of time and then we get 0:

```
avg(stddev_over_time(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1m]) != 0)
```

[image]
This works fine and values are in expected range of 0.5 (no deviation) to around 1-2 (relatively unprobable deviation).

I want to calculate the z score to detect the traffic anomaly you can cleary see at 11am in my first screenshot on the top (full loss of traffic -> alert!).

Z-Score formula is defined like follows:

```
z = (datapoint - mean_traffic) / "mean"_std_deviation
```

Thus, I want something like this:

```
z = (sum(rate[1m]) - sum(rate[10m])) / avg(stddev_over_time[10m])
```

However it does not work, because as soon as I increase the range vector of stddev_over_time to 10m,
values seem to somehow sum up and do not reflect reality anymore (std dev of more than 1). If I increase
it further, e. g. 30m I end up with values more than 5.
[image: std deviation going up when increasing range vector]
However, what I want is a moving average of std deviation of 10m, because I need it for determining whether the **current** rate of traffic deviates from the average std deviation (which the z-score is all about).

Answer (score 2):

Below is the canonical formula for [z-score](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) calculation:

```
z(qi) = (qi - avg(q)) / stddev(q)
```

In your case `q = sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1m]))`. Then both `avg()` and `stddev()` must be calculated over this `q`:

```
(
  sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1m]))
    -
  avg_over_time(sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1m]))[10m:20s])
)
  /
stddev_over_time(sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1m]))[10m:20s])
```

This query uses [subquery feature](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) for calculating [avg_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg_over_time) and [stddev_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#stddev_over_time) over non-trivial `q`.

Substitute `10m` everywhere in the query with bigger duration for calculating z-score over bigger time ranges.

P.S. As you can see, this query contains three copies of the same query `q`. This reduces readability of the query and may complicate maintenance of the query in the future when all three copies need to be updated synchronously. There is an alternative Prometheus-like monitoring solution, which solves these issues. The solution is named VictoriaMetrics + [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html). It supports e.g. [with templates](https://play.victoriametrics.com/promql/expand-with-exprs), which allow referring the same repeated subquery multiple times. For example, the query above can be simplified to the following MetricsQL query:

```
with (
  q = sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count[1m]))
)
(q - avg_over_time(q[10m:20s]))
  /
stddev_over_time(q[10m:20s])
```

P.p.s. I work on VictoriaMetrics.

Answer (score 0):

```
z = (sum(rate(metric)[1m]) - sum(avg_over_time(metric[1w])) / sum(stddev_over_time(metric[1w]))
```

Try something like this. Ref: https://towardsdatascience.com/practical-monitoring-with-prometheus-grafana-part-iii-81f019ecee19